# Excel formula if blank use last value as constant

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AU3),AVERAGE(IF($K$2>0,$K$2*B2,D2*($K$2*-1)),AVERAGE(IF(K2>0,K2*B2,D2*(K2*-1))
```

The problem is that I would like for K* to become a constant when the argument ISBLANK has been reached and not at the beginning. I have tried creating a Macro for it but I cannot figure out what I should use to make a cell constant when that argument was reached and continue on Calculating the rest with the fixed value.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between [absolute and relative cell references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-DFEC08CD-AE65-4F56-839E-5F0D8D0BACA9)?

Comment: Could you post some sample data (text, image) containing the initial data and desired resulting data. Below your post you can click **edit** and improve your question at any time.